# Spring Boot : LOGBack custom fields in every log statement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

Thought of sharing the below work as I struggled to find this info:

Requirement is to put the business correlation id(AccCode and Mac) in every log statement. This can be done by using [Mapped Diagnostic Context(MDC).](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).

No need to understand how LOGBack appender->Encoder->Layout work.

Spring boot log4j.properties has below pattern:

```
LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN=%5p
LOG_PATTERN=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] boot%X{context} - ${PID} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN} [%t] --- %c{1}: %m%n

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=${LOG_PATTERN}
```

Override LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN from application.properties with custom fields:

```
logging.pattern.level=AccCode:%X{AccCode} Mac:%X{Mac} %5p
```

Please note, now we have two extra fields defined into the layout. AccCode and Mac. Value for these new fields need to be provided using the MDC:

```
 MDC.put("AccCode", "46014" ); 
 MDC.put("Mac", "2025b9bcf");
```

Then all the log statements would have AccCode and Mac as below:

```
2016-09-12 09:11:37.574 **AccCode:46014** **Mac:2025b9bcf** DEBUG 9724 --- [main] c.c.p.sph.http.client.SphApAdminClient   : Loging out from Sph
```

Comment: Do you know what's the syntax to limit the length of those fields? For example if I want the thread id to always print only 10 chars I will do: `%15.15t`. How do I do it for custom fields like this?

Comment: The MDC is usually based on a thread local variable, this has two drawbacks:

It must be properly cleaned after being used, or you may experience information leaks if the thread is reused. Think about thread pools in web servers like Tomcat.

The information may no be properly transfered from one thread to another. Think about asynchronous calls. (source: https://gquintana.github.io/2017/12/01/Structured-logging-with-SL-FJ-and-Logback.html)